# Var_dump with echo output

Tags: php, echo, var-dump

When using var_dump with a function that have an echo like :

```
<?php 

function foo()
{
  echo 'Hello';
}

var_dump (foo());

?>
```

the output is:

`HelloNULL`

I want to know where the NULL came from

Comment: because `foo()` has no return value

Comment: nulll is returned value of foo() method

Comment: use `print_r` instead  ...that is my solution... lol  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5be3a41f0ad97d2e8fdeadc4e601c54aef14aec9) - output `Hello`. To be clear  print_r doesn't print null, false or empty strings.  The `null` is from the return.  you could return something else, but that's sort of pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the return the value of the function.

```
function foo()
{
  return 'Hello';
}

var_dump (foo());
```

Then if you want to retrieve the value of the function just do:

```
echo foo();
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, actually I know how to use echo and return but my question was to understand where the null came from and that's what I knew from the second comment

"nulll is returned value of foo() method "

but thanks anyway

Comment: NULL is returned because your function does not return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can return the value in the function foo(). Or just use print_r to print the foo() value.

```
<?php 
function foo()
{
  echo 'Hello';
}
print_r (foo());
?>
```

The output will be Hello.

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump` always shows the variable type like `int` or `string` or etc

When you call the function `foo()` and has no return type then print `Hello` and `var_dump` declares `foo()` is `NULL` since it has no return type.

```
<?php 
    function foo(){
        echo 'Hello';
        //return 'StackOverFlow';
    }
    var_dump(foo());
?>
```

Look this second one

```
<?php
    function foo2(){
    }
    var_dump(foo2()); 
?>
```

**output=>NULL**

That means `var_dump` can't declare what type of variable  function `foo2()`

Comment: If you think it's helpful for you, It's my pleasure